# .htaccess - why wont internal redirect to drupal URLs like /node/1234 work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal, drupal-7

A drupal website yet used many URLs like 
**index.php?a=a&id=1235&b=b**    (index.php + long query string , only the ID matters)

These URLs shall all be internally redirected with .htaccess to ones like this **/node/1235**     as they are already set up in drupal to permanently redirect (http 301) to  **/full-title-of-article-1235**

Now redirecting to it visiblly (http 302) works as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &id=([0-9]{4,4})
RewriteRule  ^index.php$  http://www.website.org/node/%1? [L]
```

but internally will not do anything

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &id=([0-9]{4,4})
RewriteRule  ^index.php$  /node/%1? [L]
```

i dont get why!
(of course not to confuse search engines we seek to avoid the double redirects (302-->301-->200)
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if that helps but try adding `RewriteBase /` before the `RewriteCond`

Comment: Try with `PT` flag instead of `L` flag to reevaluate the new url